# How do I disable webpack 4 code splitting?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, code-splitting

I'm using webpack 4.43.0.

How do I prevent codesplitting from happening in webpack? All these files are created - `0.bundle.js` up to `11.bundle.js` (alongside the expected `bundle.js`), when I run `webpack`. Here's my webpack config:

```
/* eslint-env node */

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './media/js/src/main.jsx',
    mode: process.env.WEBPACK_SERVE ? 'development' : 'production',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'media/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'media/js/src'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: try removing `'*'` from extensions

Comment: @AntoniSilvestrovič Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't fix the problem: https://paste.victor.computer/BkvcgXns8

Comment: Are you sure you're not loading some other webpack config? From what I see here it shouldn't do the code splitting. If not, I'd try reinstalling webpack.

Comment: @AntoniSilvestrovič yes, I'm pretty sure. Here's my project if you want to take a look yourself - see package.json. https://github.com/ccnmtl/mediathread

Comment: @nnyby Is this a React app?

Comment: @ChristosLytras yes

Comment: @nnyby are you using [Dynamic Imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) (e.g. `const Component = import('some/path')`) and/or [React Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) with [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)? If you do use any of these, then that is why webpack generates these chunk files.

Comment: @nnyby webpack bundles your application and sp(l)its out bundles based on default configuration which usually fit best practices. You can tweak it using the SplitChunksPlugin. 
So, why do you want to force everything into one bundle?

Answer (score 34):

You can use webpack's [`LimitChunkCountPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/) to limit the chunk count produced by code splitting:

In your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');   

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    })
  ],
  ...
};
```

---

You could also [pass the `--optimize-max-chunks` option](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/#usage-via-cli) to the `webpack` command directly.

So, in your `package.json` file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --optimize-max-chunks 1",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Now, when you run `npm run build`, webpack will build only one file (or "chunk").

Answer (score 1):

```
// Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build
build: {
  scopeHoisting: true,
  vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
  showProgress: true,
  gzip: false,
  analyze: false,
  distDir: 'dist',
  productName:'pos_host_ui',
  minify:true,
  
  // Options below are automatically set depending on the env, set them if you want to override
  // extractCSS: false,

  // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-webpack
  extendWebpack (cfg) {
      const webpack = require('webpack');   
      cfg.plugins.push(
            new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
              maxChunks: 1
                })
      );
      
      cfg.module.rules.push({
        resourceQuery: /blockType=i18n/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        use: [
          { loader: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader' },
          { loader: 'yaml-loader' },
        ]
      });
   }
```